# SearchView does not iconify

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview

In my app I am using an `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` (from support v7 library) to provide search from action bar.
I setup this view in MainActivity, with the following code:

### MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SupportMenuItem searchMenuItem = (SupportMenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            // OnQueryTextListener body
            ...
        });

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Then in a Fragment i need to ensure that the SearchView is collapsed:

### MyFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchView.clearFocus(); // Try to prevent SearchView to steal focus. No luck!
    searchView.setIconified(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // other stuff
}
```

The problem is that not only the SearchView does not collapse (I tried also with `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem)` with no success: it returns always `false`), but also the SearchView "steals" focus at every fragment transaction (e.g. replace one fragment with another), so when the "new" fragment is displayed, the SearchView has focus, so it shows its suggestions.

I also noticed that if I do not call `setHasOptionsMenu` then the problem of "stealing focus" does not occur.
Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding an invalidateOptionsMenu in your query text listener. That was what I had to do to work around this bug.